# Array elements containing 'this' is returning undefined when declared inside an object literal

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the process of learning object literals and was experimenting with the following code. I'm trying to get the values of inputs based on the css class (`.one`,`.two`). I have created the two 'variables',`oneInput` and `twoInput` to get the elements that match each class. Then I've assigned the two variables to the array, which I'm planning to access within `getInputValues` function but the array is returning undefiend. I did read a few threads about object literals and the use of 'this' but not sure how to overcome this situation.

However, if I create another function inside the object and return the same array it works but I'd like to know if I can achieve the same with this current implementation.

```js
var myObj = {
  oneInput: $('.one'),
  twoInput: $('.two'),
  arr: [this.oneInput, this.twoInput],

  getInputValues: function() {
    console.log(this.arr);
  },

  eventBind: function() {
    this.oneInput.on('blur', this.getInputValues.bind(this));
  }
}

myObj.eventBind();
```

```css
.one,
.two {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="one" />
<input type="text" class="one" />
<input type="text" class="one" />
<input type="text" class="one" />

<hr />

<input type="text" class="two" />
<input type="text" class="two" />
<input type="text" class="two" />
<input type="text" class="two" />
```

Any help, adivce is massively appreciated.

Comment: This article explains the issue and the approach to use very well: https://clubmate.fi/self-referencing-object-literal-in-javascript/

Comment: *"but I'd like to know if I can achieve the same with this current implementation."* No. the object doesn't exist at the moment the arrays is created. `this` doesn't refer to the object.

Comment: 'this' inside the function is not the same 'this' inside the object.

Comment: `No. the object doesn't exist at the moment the arrays is created` Sorry, Felix, I didn't quite understand that. :(

Comment: Great article Rory! Many thanks for sharing...

Comment: When you do `{foo: [bar()]}` this is the order of operations: Call function `bar()`, remember the return value. Create the array and set the first element to be the remembered value. Create the object and set the array as the value of the `foo` property. In short: array elements > array (property values) > object. At the moment the array elements are evaluated the object doesn't exist yet and therefore none of the elements can refer to a property of the object. It works if you put the array inside a function because the function is called some time *after* the object was created.

Comment: Many thanks for the explanation, Felix - much appreciated!